# questions/{id}/timeline documentation: timeline_type values not listed

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

The timeline_type for post timelines just says "string" for the "values". From a cursory look at a few questions, I've seen the following types of events:

- question
- answer
- comment
- revision
- votes

The user timelines documentation enumerates the possible event types. Could this be added for post timelines as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.